# Cannot open alsamixer

Tags: command-line, sound, alsa

Sound doesn't work, no input/output sound device is detected and I cannot open `alsamixer`:

```
$ alsamixer 
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

$ alsamixer -c 1
invalid card index: 1
try `alsamixer --help' for more information

$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 1 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfde78000 irq 27
# On raspberry pi
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
 bcm2835 ALSA
```

Kernel Information:

```
$ uname -r
5.0.0-25-generic

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

Output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`

```
# On my PC
$ ls -l /dev/snd/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 iun 23 13:37 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 iun 23 13:37 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 iun 23 13:37 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 iun 23 13:37 pcmC1D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 iun 23 13:37 pcmC1D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 iun 23 13:37 pcmC1D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 iun 23 13:37 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 iun 23 13:37 timer

# On Raspberry Pi 3
$ ls -l /dev/snd/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 apr  1 20:23 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 iun 23 11:39 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 iun 23 11:39 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 iun 23 11:39 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 iun 23 11:39 pcmC0D2p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 iun 23 11:39 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 iun 23 11:39 timer

# Raspberry Pi 2
$ ls -l /dev/snd/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 apr  1 20:23 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 apr  1 20:23 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 apr  1 20:23 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 apr  1 20:23 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 apr  1 20:23 pcmC0D2p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 apr  1 20:23 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 apr  1 20:23 timer
```

How to solve this so that I can access the sound output and eventually make it work nicely?

Comment: that looks not good. `cat /proc/asound/cards` are you running pulseaudio? Which desktop session?

Comment: @nobody I connect to it via VNC Viewer, but I have physical headphones connect to the machine. I added the output of that command. I am pretty sure it's not a hardware issue because it used to work with Windows 7. And in fact, I have the exact same problem with a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: `HDA Intel` everywhere means that the driver did not recognize the particular HDA controller chip. Which kernel version? Which hardware?

Comment: Oh, VNC. By. :)

Comment: @CL. It's an old Pentium IV computer, with 2GB of RAM. I'm not sure if you are interested in any specific output of a command...

Comment: @nobody Well, I get the same output via `ssh` as well.

Comment: `lspci`. Which kernel version?

Comment: @CL. Updated with the output of lspci.

Comment: @CL. Any ideas how to fix this? `lspci` does not output anything on my rpi2.

Comment: The BCM2835 is not a PCI device. If the devices show up in `/proc/asound/cards`, you do not appear to have a hardware problem. What is the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`?

Comment: @CL. I added the output of the command on pi2, pi3, and PC, all of them having the same issue.

Comment: Is your user a member of the audio group?

Comment: @CL. No, the user was not member of the `audio` group. I ran `sudo usermod -g audio $USER` and now `groups $USER` shows `audio` too.

Comment: Does `aplay -l` etc. now work?